# Oracle automatic GRANT permissions

Tags: database, oracle, database-schema, database-management

I'm trying to analyze the security that DBMS provides, the following scenario provides a brief description of what I'm looking for.

// The current user connected to the database is "master"

// 1. Basic step to create the new user

```
CREATE USER slave
IDENTIFIED BY SlavePassword
DEFAULT TABLESPACE SomeTablespace;
```

// 2. Grant basic roles to the new user

```
GRANT CONNECT TO slave;
GRANT RESOURCE TO slave;
```

// 3. The new user "slave" is now connected to the database

// The user "slave" creates database objects (tables, procedures, etc.), and granted privileges from other users of the system

How to allow the creator "master" to obtain whatever privileges the created user "slave" has or would have in the future, without explicit permission from the "slave" user?

I know that the slave can grant any of his privileges to other users, but is there a special privilege that allows other users to obtain future privileges the "slave" would have?

I'm using Oracle and I'm not sure if other DBMS allow this scenario.

Comment: You may want to avoid RESOURCE.  From the [Database Security Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e16543/authorization.htm#sthref647): "Note: Oracle recommends that you design your own roles for database security rather than relying on this role. This role may not be created automatically by future releases of Oracle Database."

Answer (score 3):

The only way to do this using Database Vault.  If you create a realm for the "slave" user and add the "master" user to that realm, then the master user will have permissions on all objects in that schema.  This Tutorial from OTN

http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=44785:24:0::NO:24:P24_CONTENT_ID,P24_PREV_PAGE:4544,29

walks you through creating the realm.  You would just go through the additional step of adding "master" as a realm participant

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle account model does not work in the way you describe.  The user which creates a user has no special privileges over the objects which that user creates.  All users are born in a state of manumission

There are only two levels of object privilege:

- privileges granted on specific objects in individual schemas
- privileges granted on all objects of a given type in every schema, gained through the ANY privilege.

The first level is the mechanism you mention by which SLAVE grants rights on its objects to MASTER.  The second level is extremely powerful because it applies across all the objects owned by all users, including the Oracle DBMS accounts such as SYS.  Consequently it is normal for only DBA users to have the ANY level privileges.

The reason for this state of affairs is that Oracle employs users and schemas as the mechanism for controlling access to data and functionality.  A user which is wholly owned by another user doesn't make any sense in that context.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do this with a [proxy user](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_4003.htm#i2058312).

This will let MASTER see SLAVE's objects.  However, when MASTER connects as SLAVE, it can no longer see the MASTER objects.

```
--Create master user
create user master identified by master;
grant connect, create table to master;

--Create slave user, and grant proxy to master
create user slave identified by slave;
grant connect, create table to slave;
alter user slave grant connect through master;

--Connect as master, create a table
sqlplus master/master@orcl2
create table master_table(a number);
exit;

--Connect as slave, create a table
sqlplus slave/slave@orcl2
create table slave_table(a number);
exit;

--Connect as master, but pretending to be slave
sqlplus master[slave]/master@orcl2

--You can see the slave tables 
select * from slave_table;
    no rows selected

--But you cannot see the master tables
select * from master.master_table;
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-00942: table or view does not exist              *
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of your request here... if you want "master" user to automatically access "slave" objects then you can do this by granting dba to master

```
grant dba to master;
```

if you intend something else please clarify your question with more details to help you.

Comment: This could be part of the answer, where "master" can access "slave" objects. What I really wanted is simply copying whatever new privileges the "slave" obtains to the "master" user. Consider "USER X" granting new privileges to "slave", the "master" should have a copy of those privileges as well, without EXPLICIT transfer of privileges to "master".

Comment: Only DBAs should be granted the `DBA` role.  It is not clear from the question that MASTER is a DBA account - although only DBAs should be creating users.